# AWStats SQL Tool?

Tags: sql, awstats

does anyone ever heard of a tool/script/etc. which allows to import an AWStats created logfile ( e.g. as text or xml ) into a SQL-DB?

I just want to figure out if i really have to write a parser-script myself...

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need the compiled information created by AWStats rather than the raw data from the initial server (e.g Apache).  The Drupal.org folk seem to have done a little [work on parsing the AWStats output](http://drupal.org/node/324675), is that any help?

If the raw data from e.g. Apache is enough, you can import that into the database, see for example:
[Writing Apache's Logs to MySQL](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/apache/2005/02/10/database_logs.html)

Comment: Yes, i need the infos already processed by AWStats... my final goal is to put "some" of the infos, generated by AWStats, in a DB and assign them to different users/groups, etc...